# How to structure this DB in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a form that saves the input in a SQLite database in android. The first part is relatively simple and common to all the database rows (name, age, occupation, etc.).

The last part, however, depends on the user's choice. For example: if the user chooses the hobby Hiking, the form will display some unique questions with unique table entries. If he chooses the hobby Gardening, there will be different table entries as well and so on.

How can this be achieved in the best way? I suspect it has something to do with other tables and foreign keys, but can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple key value set of tables may be an easy solution:

```
Selected Topic | Associated Question Key


Question Key | Question # | Question
```

This two table structure will allow you to look up based off of the selected topic and then the questions for that topic. Depending on how the survey is structured, the database schema would need to change (for example multiple different paths, fixed # questions, etc). But this basic outline should provide a basis for a dynamic form

Comment: Do you know of any tutorial or something I can follow to learn to do this in SQLite per se? Thanks, btw!

Comment: a few links: database normalization (any db, useful for schema design): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization
, http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/ : a tutorial on sqlite in android, a useful tool to debug a sqlite database (you can script here and see the results in a gui): http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll need this!